# Can I limit IIS to use one rather than two processors

Tags: iis, windows-7

Our ASP.NET app uses a component that is licensed by the number of processor cores. Unfortunately, our customer wants to deploy the app onto a multi-function server (IIS, SQL Server, file server, etc.) that exceeds the number of processor cores for which the customer is licensed: they are allowed four cores but have two processors with four cores each.  Can I configure IIS to use only one processor?

So I tried to set application pools settings

in applicationpool -> advance setting -> process affinity enable =ture
and I  have set number of working process =1

After I have checked in task manager w3wp.exe-> set affinity its all core are selected

Where did I make error?

Comment: Limit it to specific processors (cores) using the affinity mask.

Comment: Which likely will not help as the licensing component still sees too many processors. A virtual machine may be the only option. Also - check licensing agreements. It is likely this is going to result in an illegal setup and thus a not licensed component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the affinity mask. By default it is all 1's (run on any core) so you would need to set it to a value with 4 bits set for 4 cores. For example to `15` for processors 0,1,2 and 3. (`0xF`).

[image: CPU section of application pool settings]

Comment: Which likely will not help because if the license check is woth a grain it will not check the affinity mask.

Comment: if i set affinity maskto 15 then i checked in task manager w3wp.exe-> set affinity its all core are selected

Comment: i am using core i3 with 4 core

Comment: Technically a dual core i3 with hyperthreading for 4 logical cores.